# Django - set ONE session_key for every visitor/browser and remember it without logging in

Tags: django, django-views, django-sessions

I'm trying to create e-commerce cart in Django and got into trouble with **session_key**. When I'm logged in the admin page, my session_key is always the same. But after I logout, my session_key is `None`. So I call `request.session.create()` but after refreshing the page, session_key is again `None`. What is a problem since I'd like to pair every cart to session_key.

Is there any way how to force Django to remember user's browser/session_key? Or how could I implement the same logic as is for logged users for not logged users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found solution.
It's actually super-easy since I just made this function in view.py

```
def set_or_check_sessionid(request):
    session_id = request.session._get_or_create_session_key()
    response = HttpResponse('sessionID_set')
    tomorrow = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = 1)
    response.set_cookie('sessionid', session_id, expires=tomorrow)
    print(session_id)
    return response
```

this simple function is called on load of every document from JS with simple call via defined url.py as `path('ajax/getSessionKey/', get_session_id, name='get_session_id')`

with JS that loads in every document `$.get("/ajax/set_or_check_sessionid/");`